# Why is the performance of my ClickHouse query getting so much worse?

Tags: clickhouse

I did `OPTIMIZE TABLE ... FINAL;` to my table. Then I did `SELECT ... FINAL ...;` with condition by `date_time` column (all data is before OPTIMIZE was called). 136 millions rows were processed, ellapsed: 0.847 sec.

I repeated the query, but moved `date_time` condition 1 minute forward (where table include data which isn't OPTIMIZED). I got 70.000 extra processed rows (+0,05% rows processed). And I got `Elapsed: 3,605 sec.` That's a huge difference.

If I don't have *FINAL* in *SELECT*, it works fine. So, my questions are:

1/ How does it work? Why did I get so bad performance?

2/ Can I be sure that all data before OPTIMIZE will always be so fast?

My table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE campaign_impression ON CLUSTER 'statistics'
(
    date_time               DateTime('UTC'),
    campaign_id             Int64,
    impression_environment  Enum('WEB' = 1, 'IN_APP' = 2),
    action_type             Enum('IMPRESSION' = 1, 'CLICK' = 2),
    event_log_id            Int64,
    hit_log_id              UInt64,
    banner_id               UInt64,
    ad_group_id             UInt64
) ENGINE = ReplicatedReplacingMergeTree('/clickhouse/tables/statistics/{shard}/default/campaign_impression', '{replica}')
    PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(date_time)
    ORDER BY (campaign_id, date_time, event_log_id)
    PRIMARY KEY (campaign_id, date_time);
```

Performed query:

```sql
SELECT  toStartOfInterval(toTimeZone(date_time, 'UTC'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS interval_start,
        action_type,
        impression_environment,
        count(*) AS count
FROM campaign_impression FINAL
WHERE date_time >= '2023-01-13'
  AND date_time < '2024-01-16 14:35:00'
  AND campaign_id = 491
GROUP BY action_type, interval_start, impression_environment
ORDER BY interval_start DESC
    SETTINGS do_not_merge_across_partitions_select_final = 1
    FORMAT Null;
```

ClickHouse version: 23.12

Answer (score 1):

**Performance**

---

Your query will scan all parts of the table. Let's see the query details:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN json = 1, indexes = 1 SELECT toStartOfInterval(toTimeZone(date_time, 'UTC'), INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS interval_start,
        action_type,
        impression_environment,
        count(*) AS count
   FROM campaign_impression FINAL
  WHERE date_time >= '2023-01-13'
    AND date_time < '2024-01-16 14:35:00'
    AND campaign_id = 491
  GROUP BY action_type, interval_start, impression_environment
  ORDER BY interval_start DESC
SETTINGS do_not_merge_across_partitions_select_final = 1
 FORMAT Vertical
```

You'll see that all parts was selected:

[image: parts1]

But your table is partitioned by `toYYYYMM(date_time)`. Let's change `WHERE condition` to:

```
WHERE toYYYYMM(date_time) >= 202301
  AND toYYYYMM(date_time) < 202401
  AND campaign_id = 491
```

and check `Plans`:

[image: parts2]

As you can see `0` parts was selected / scanned. The less values are for `Selected Parts` / `Selected Granules` is the better.

**Optimize**

---

[Avoid Optimize Final](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/optimize/avoidoptimizefinal). `OPTIMIZE FINAL` requires a lot memory(especially if you have large table). So if the process works now, this doesn't mean that it will work in a month when there is more data.

Queries that use `FINAL` are executed slightly [slower](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/select/from#drawbacks)
than similar queries and requires additional compute and memory resources.